# change element style on scroll event in Angular

Tags: angular

I just want to share this..

"in the next example after header section with 100vh I want to change navbar`s position from absolute to fixed".

you can react to scroll event by simply add scroll event in app.component.html:

```
<header style="height: 100vh;"></header>
<section (scroll)="onScroll($event)" style="position: relative;">
   <nav style="position: absloute;" #nav>may nav</nav>
</section>
```

then in app.component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('nav') elementRef: ElementRef;

 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

 @HostListener('document:scroll', ['$event']) 
  onScroll(event: Event) {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > window.innerHeight) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'class-name')
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'class-name')
    }
  }
```

you can point at specific scroll point by change `window.innerHeight` to any value "by getting the height to target element".
you can also trigger animation at this point..
I hope that can help any one.